# Center custom TitleView containing an UIImage and UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage

I checked all the other answers, but I cannot get it to work using what they say:

I have a UIView myTitle, with Frame (0,0,320,44) which contains an UIImage and a UILabel. The UIImage and the UILabel are fine and look fine, but I cannot seem to figure out how to center myTitle.

```
self.navigationItem.titleView =  myTitle;
```

It shows up and looks ok, but much too far to the left. It seems to (logically) be related to the left bar button (the back button) which is auto generated by the framework when I push a controller. That barbutton has a varying width based on that and it changes the x of myTitle view based on that.

So, where can I get the width of the left (and right) barbuttons so I can figure out how to put myTitle that in the center?

I notice when I change the width of myTitle it (logically) will center (because the UIImage and UILabel are centered within  myTitle).

Comment: Forget about frames, use autolayout.

Answer (score 0):

To have more control, instead of having the left bar button auto -generated, set it using code as below.

```
UIButton *leftButton =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[leftButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 44)];
[leftButton setTitle:@"back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[leftButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[leftButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftButton];
```

Now you can perfectly adjust the frame of titleView with out much problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found two ways in which it works;

- Like Cy-4AH suggested, using autolayout; her/his answer would be the answer
- Not using autolayout it was much simpler than I thought; if i make the titleView Width to fit it's content exactly, it automatically works; is that done with auto layout internally?

Hope this helps someone.